# One dimensional array into two dimensional array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

Hey how can I convert one dimensional array with x elements into two dimensional array with x/2 elements? This is my code:

```
Function std_norm(N, num_of_sim)
Randomize
Dim norm() As Double
randoms = N * num_of_sim - 1
ReDim norm(randoms)
For i = 0 To randoms
    rand = Rnd
    If rand = 0 Then rand = Rnd
    norm(i) = Application.NormSInv(rand)
Next i
mean = WorksheetFunction.Average(norm)
std = WorksheetFunction.StDev(norm)
For i = 0 To randoms
    norm(i) = (norm(i) - mean) / std
Next i
ReDim Preserve norm(num_of_sim - 1, N - 1)

std_norm = norm
End Function
```

If I take `N=2` and `num_of_sim=3` then my array `norm` has 6 elements. Then I try to do two dimensional array with size `(N-1,num_of_sim-1)`.

Why I get an error `subscript out of range`?

Comment: People usually have trouble with Redim because they want to redim more than the last dimension. in a multidimensional array.

Comment: I think once you set the dimension(s) of a dynamic array you cannot change it *while preserving values*. Also you can change the size of **the last** dimension only. Consider declaring another 2-d array, populate it in a loop and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a result of changing dimension of the array -> resizing from 1-dimension array into 2-dimensions.
As per documentation from Microsoft:

> If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension **and you can't change the number of dimensions at all**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement 

What you did, was create one-dimensional array(0 to 5):

```
ReDim norm(randoms)
```

And then you want to convert it into two-dimensional array (1 to 2, 1 to 1):

```
ReDim Preserve norm(num_of_sim - 1, N - 1)
```

I don't know what you want to achieve, but most probably you need to create new array variable which you will resize the way you want (two dimensions) and you will populate it with values from first array.